# How this Python code works that stores all text files in a list

Tags: python

I am a beginner of Python. I am working on a practice that copy all text files's content to a spreadsheet, the following code will store will text files in certain folder to a list object:

```
path=".\\Excel Spreadsheets"

text_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path) if filename.endswith(".txt")]
```

I have a hard time to understand how second line works, since in the text book, I only see the example like:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
       os.unlike(filename) #...do something..
```

I mean I only know how second code works, like loops via a path, and the if statement check the text files, then do something..

but the first code is too compressed for me, is it possible to break it into a simple or more logic way?

Comment: `[x for x in list_y if meets_condition(x)]` this means select only those values of x for which meets_condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `text_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path) if filename.endswith(".txt")]`, text_files will be a list of the filenames. This type of statement is called list comprehension and a special attribute of python that makes it so concise. It's equivalent to the following code:

```
text_files = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        text_files.append(filename)
```

Looping through the elements in text_files will get you the same result as the second bit of code:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
         print(filename)
```

is equivalent to

```
text_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path) if filename.endswith(".txt")]
for filename in text_files:
    print(filename)
```

For more information on list comprehension, see here: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python